# Как перезапустить скрипт после ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

На сайте есть несколько **блоков с картинками**. Скрипт в каждом блоке вешает класс **"image-hover"** на первую картинку. Так же на сайте есть подключённые фильтры битрикса. Которые фильтруют эти самые **блоки  с картинками**.  Как после использования фильтра перезапустить мой скрипт, чтобы он применялся к новым(отфильтрованным) блокам с картинками.

Вот сам сайт http://rem.mosplitka.ru/portfolio/dizayn-proekty
Вот аякс запрос битрикса https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/qBZxvdW

```js
//Мой код

function someSlider(){
    let imageSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.image-slider');

    imageSlider.forEach((item) => {
        let first = item.querySelectorAll('.image-slider__image');
        first[0].classList.add('image-hover');
    });
}

someSlider();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">   
    <a href="#" class="slider__item">
      <img class="slider__img" src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
      ...
      <img class="slider__img" src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
    </a>        
    ...        
    <a href="#" class="slider__item">
      <img class="slider__img" src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
      ...
      <img class="slider__img" src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/351256/

Comment: Если вы можете редактировать этот скрипт битрикса, то нужно найти то место в нем, которое выполняется после выполнения фильтрации и добавить туда someSlider(); 
Конечно, редактировать сторонний код - ужасная практика, но судя по беглому поиску, такое распространено среди пользователей этого скрипта.

Comment: @doox911 не помогло, зато узнал что-то новое

Comment: @Dzorogh по сути так и сделали